# vala: how to cast void * to uint[]?

Tags: vala

I want to call `Gdk.Pixbuf.from_data()` constructor in order to wrap a video frame from GStreamer into a pixbuf. The constructor accepts the pointer to memory as `uint8[]`. But I have a `void *` variable (`Gst.Video.Frame.data[0]`) which points to the start of the data. I know `uint8[]` is not just a pointer but rather a type knowing about where memory starts and how far it spans. But for `Gdk.Pixbuf.from_data()` it doesn't really matter because C signature of the function accepts just `const guchar *` and the length is inferred from other parameters like stride and height.

So... How do I correctly wrap my `void *` pointer into a `uint[]` array?

```
Video.Frame frame = {};
...
var pixbuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf.from_data((uint8[])frame.data[0], ...);
```

The casting above doesn't work because vala generates C code which copies data from `memory` to the newly created array but with incorrect length. Firstly, it's obvious that vala itself cannot know the length to which `void *` points and secondly, I don't need any copying, I just need a simple casting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know where you got the `void*`, but for the most part if you have a pointer in Vala you're doing it wrong. There are exceptions, mainly if you're using libxml, but they are few and far between. You should take a look at the code which creates a `void*` and think about if there is a better way, like maybe `new uint8[x]` instead of `malloc(x)`.

Casting `void*` to `uint8[]` only requires a cast, but the length will be set to -1. `Gdk.Pixbuf.from_data` doesn't actually need length (it calculates it based on `height` and `rowstride`), though, so that shouldn't be a problem. However, in general you probably want to do something like

```
unowned uint8[] data = (uint8[]) memory;
data.length = whatever;
```

Since some functions do require a length. Many also don't check the length argument for using it, which means an invalid length can easily trigger a segfault. Basically, it's a good habit to get into, and it's generally easier than checking every argument to see if the `array_length = false` CCode attribute is set.

The reason Vala generates a copy is because `Gdk.Pixbuf.from_data` takes ownership of the data. You need to tell Vala to transfer ownership of the data (using `(owned)`).

Putting it all together:

```
unowned uint8[] data = (uint8[]) memory;
data.length = whatever;
Gdk.Pixbuf pb = new Gdk.Pixbuf.from_data(data, ...);
```

But note that you'll still end up with a copy when the data is passed to `Gdk.Pixbuf.from_data`. There is just no way around the copy since `Gdk.Pixbuf.from_data` takes ownership, unless you can transfer ownership of the original data.

Comment: Well, it seems it's not that simple. First, even if I don't call `Gdk.Pixbuf.from_data()` at all but just cast `void *` to `uint8[]` I get copying in the generated C code. And second, if I manually set `data.length` to whatever in the C code copying happens *before* the length is set correctly (that is with -1 anyway).

Comment: Also it seems not fully right to me that `Gdk.Pixbuf.from_data()` takes ownership of the memory. Its C signature works fine if a user just want to wrap some piece of data without any memory management (for that `destroy_fn` must be set `NULL`). And this is exactly my case. I have a video frame which may be allocated anywhere and I just want to access it through a pixbuff without any freeing it when the pixbuff gets destroyed. I only guarantee that as long as the pixbuf exists the referenced memory stays valid.

Comment: `uint8[] data = (uint8[]) memory;` generates a copy because `data` is owned. `unowend uint8[] data = (uint8[]) memory;`, OTOH, will not copy the data. You're right that you should use unowned there, though, since the pointer doesn't have an associated length (seriously, don't use pointers in Vala). I'll update the answer.

Comment: Vala can't capture some of the stranger semantics of C function calls, like `NULL` for functions where you aren't transferring ownership. For one thing, how *would* you transfer ownership if you wanted? Also, keep in mind that it's unsafe to not transfer ownership since you would then need to keep the data alive elsewhere or you'll end up accessing invalid memory (or worse, run into the ABA problem, which is very hard to debug). One option would be to use `from_bytes`, since `GLib.Bytes` is a bit more flexible about memory management.

Comment: Sure, it's safer to use reference counting and cool stuff like that but in my case I don't have such an option (Gst.Vidio.Frames expose only `void *`). OTOH, I know for sure that in my case memory remains valid at least until the pixbuf exists (tempting to say "I'm a big boy and I know what I'm doing" :-) :-) :-)). So I just need a trivial wrapper w/o any memory mangement.

Comment: And really I wonder how `Gdk.Pixbuf.from_data()` is supposed to work in vala? Ok, suppose I'm passing ownership of `uint8[]` to the pixbuf. How then will it free it? One guess, I can set `destroy_fn`. But to what functor? Is there an explicit deleter for `uint8[]`? Probably `g_free()`?

Comment: Also I'm not sure about `Glib.Bytes` because it seems it has the same limitations. It can't wrap `unowned uint8[]` (although it can be done with the C functions)

Comment: It looks `Glib.Bytes.new_with_owner<T>` accepts `unowned uint8[]` and returns a not-doing-anything-at-destruction wrapper of `void *`, given `null` destructor. The generated C code doesn't contain any memory copying in this case. Hmm, but then I get memory leaking when I put the Bytes-based Pixbuf into `Gdk.cairo_set_source_pixbuf(cr, pixbuf, 0, 0)`. There happens memory copying but then nobody releases it. I need to figure out why...

Comment: It looks like there is a bug in `gdk-pixbuf`. If someone calls `gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels_with_length()` on a pixbuf created from GBytes with not `g_free()` data destructor (in my case it's `NULL`) GBytes creates a copy of data pointer which will be put into the pixbuf's `pixels` field. The problem is that data will not be freed at `gdk_pixbuf_finalize()` since `destroy_fn` hasn't been set to anything neither at `gdk_pixbuf_new_from_bytes()` nor at  `gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels_with_length()` where `pixels` field gets updated.

Comment: Use `GLib.Bytes.static`, not `GLib.Bytes.new_with_owner`.